# Geometrical Interpretation of Bessel's Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Bessel's inequality
Let $(e_k)$ be an orthonormal sequence in an inner product space X. Then, for every $x\in X $ 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2 \leq||x||^2$

I want to interpret Bessel's inequality geometrically when $ X=R^r$ and $r\geq n$ 
When looking at $R^2$, the LHS behaves as the sum of squares of the side lengths of a triangle and RHS as the third side of the triangle.
But I don't know whether this is correct, and I would like to know how we interpret this in higher dimensions.

Comment: Your interpretation about the sides and hypotenuse of a right triangle is essentially correct. Alternatively, projecting a Euclidean vector into a coordinate subspace (namely, setting some of the components to $0$) cannot make the vector longer, i.e., each "shadow" of a vector into a coordinate subspace has magnitude no larger than the original vector.

Comment: As a typographocal note, `\langle` and `\rangle` give angle brackets with delimiter spacing. (The greater-than/less-than symbols are spaced like binary relations.) Code such as `\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}` allows you to type `\Brak{x, e_{k}}` and get $\langle x, e_{k}\rangle$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for both comments